# Checksum in Perl

Tags: perl, checksum

I am a java developer, I need to understand some perl code and need to convert it in java. Here is the snippet.

```
my @var = map hex,split //,A8F000000F4241;
my $sum=0;
# calculate checksum of odd bytes and twisted even bytes    
$sum-=$_ for map((0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15)[$_], @var[0,2,4,6,8,10,12]), @var[1,3,5,7,9,11,13];       
print $sum ;
```

I am really finding it hard to understand what it is doing in line number 4. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your perl code is incomplete; it sets a scalar `$var` but later reads an array `@var`; they are two different things.

Comment: There you go. Corrected.

Comment: that's not right, either. it sets a one-element array but uses 14 elements.  can you show us the actual, working snippet you want to understand?

Comment: Sorry. Corrected again. Hope it is correct now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script should be rewritten as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

# Split the string into a list of all character
my @elem = split //, 'A8F000000F4241';
dump @elem;

# convert each element to a hexadecimal number
my @var = map hex, @elem;
dump @var;

# list all number between 0 and 15, even then odd
my @numbers = (0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15);

# >Pick number in @numbers at position defined in @var (even position in @var)
my @l = map($numbers[$_], @var[0,2,4,6,8,10,12]);
dump@l;

# initialization
my $sum=0;

# loop on the two arrays 
for (@l, @var[1,3,5,7,9,11,13]) {
  $sum -= $_ ;
}
print $sum ;
```

Is that clearer for you?

Comment: Got it ! This is so much better. Thanks a ton. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Toto, I upvoted but seeing “this Perl SHOULD be…” might be better written as “this Perl COULD be…” Otherwise one is making/implying a style assertion and you might as well say, “you SHOULD edit code with Emacs.” :P